# Is there a way to check for Nameservers using Linux?

Tags: linux, nameserver

If a domain name has not been registered, but the nameservers have been setup, is there a way I can check using the commandline on linux if the nameservers exist without having the domain name registered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dig @ns1.example.com www.example.com
```

Will send a query directly to `ns1.example.com` for the name `www.example.com`, without doing recursive lookup from the root nameservers.

Answer (score 0):

Use "dig" at the command prompt. Check this quick howto out [here](http://www.madboa.com/geek/dig/). Point it to the nameserver you've set up internally to see the responses.